# Footer section is overlapping the body content

Tags: html, css

I have a background image on the header section and Text are horizontal and vertically center of the div. I am getting some issue on footer section.

Footer section is overlaying the body content.

Why overlaying? Because I have used `.body_wrapper{height:100%;}` to display the background image. If I remove the `height:100%` then not getting the overlay issue but my header image not displaying.

Why `.body_wrapper{height:100%;}` ? because I have two parent div.

Would you help me out in this?

[image]

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.main_wrapper {
  display: inline;
}

.body_wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 90px;
}

.bg_contact {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url('https://wallpaper-house.com/data/out/6/wallpaper2you_106757.jpg');
}

.banner_bg {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.contact_header_content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.contact_header_content h2 {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #fff;
}

.contact_header_content p {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

.contact_header {
  position: relative;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #222;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_wrapper">
  <div class="body_wrapper">
    <div class="bg_contact banner_bg contact_header">
      <div class="contact_header_content">
        <h2>We sould love to hear back from you.</h2>
        <p>Whether you have question about features, pricing, need a demo or anything e s Our team is ready to answer all your questions. </p>
        <div class="btn_slider">
          <a href="#" class="i_btn i_btn_bg text_cap">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <section>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    </section>
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have put your **footer div** outside of your **body_wrapper div**

i have modified your code snipet, please check and let me know

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.main_wrapper {
  display: inline;
}

.body_wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 90px;
}

.bg_contact {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url('https://wallpaper-house.com/data/out/6/wallpaper2you_106757.jpg');
}

.banner_bg {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.contact_header_content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.contact_header_content h2 {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #fff;
}

.contact_header_content p {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 25px 0;
}

.contact_header {
  position: relative;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #222;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_wrapper">
    <div class="body_wrapper">
        <div class="bg_contact banner_bg contact_header">
            <div class="contact_header_content">
                <h2>We sould love to hear back from you.</h2>
                <p>Whether you have question about features, pricing, need a demo or anything e s Our team is ready to answer all your questions. </p>
                <div class="btn_slider">
                    <a href="#" class="i_btn i_btn_bg text_cap">Contact Us</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <section>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
                dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
                dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

        </section>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
                dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, It's working but I just want to know Is it a right way? I mean  header - bodycontent - footer. We have to use like this way? right?

Comment: i think you should take a look at [this](https://www.quackit.com/css/grid/tutorial/create_a_website_layout.cfm). it will give you basic idea about grid base layout design